# How to set border bottom on UISearchBar in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uisearchbar

I'd like to specify the bottom border color of a UISearchBar. I've seen a lot of answers that will help get rid of the border, or set the border color as a whole, but I just want to set the border color for the bottom border. Here is my code:

`searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
 searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor`

Is there a way to set borderColor for *just* the bottom border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a subview to your textField like this

```
let frame = CGRectMake(0, textField.frame.size.height - 1, textField.frame.size.width, 1)
let border = UIView(frame: frame)
border.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
textField.addSubview(border)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using swift version below 3(<3.0), then this below code should work -

```
let border = CALayer()
let width = CGFloat(2.0)
border.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: searchBar.frame.size.height + width, width:  searchBar.frame.size.width, height: searchBar.frame.size.height)
        
border.borderWidth = width
searchBar.layer.addSublayer(border)
searchBar.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

I am using swift 3.0, but before adding this comment i was testing this feature in my end, and it wasn't working for me. I am not sure why but this is the correct code to show a border at the bottom of any element.

I tried using insertinglayout at the bottom of the search bar but it's not working.

```
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(border, below:searchBar.layer)
```

I won't tell you this is an answer. But this will give you an idea how to add a layout at the bottom of an specific item.